# how can i install magento 2.4.4 and 2.3.3 having different server requirements on local system for development in linux

Tags: magento2, database, linux

i know that we can switch between different version of php in ubuntu with the commands

```
sudo a2dismod php7.1
sudo a2enmod php5.6
```

but the mysql requirement for the old and new magento setups are also different , i tried to look for switch between different mysql versions but could not find the anywhere how this can be achieved . i want to setup different magento project on my linux machine , If anyone using the same on linux please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

**Database**

You can install 2 version of MySQL and serve by different port. Example 3306 for 8.0 and another one for 5.x. Setup `host` with port in `env.php`

**PHP**

Anyway, you will need to link or run with correct PHP version in console. Magento 2.4.4 is still compatible with PHP 7.4 and i don't remember any parts which require 8.1

For webserver I suggest to use nginx + php-fpm with the same logic about ports. Example 9074 for PHP 7.4 and 9000 for 8.1

**P.S.**

You can try to start to use **Docker** and it might save some time with software versions in future.